# Java How to stop multiple audio loops from playing

Tags: java

```
    package sounds;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Playlist
{

    private Clip activeClip;

    /**
     * Creates an audio clip from a sound file.
     */
    public Clip createClip (String soundFile)
    {
        String fileName = "/sounds/" + soundFile + ".wav";
        try (BufferedInputStream sound = new BufferedInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName)))
        {
            // Create and return a Clip that will play a sound file. There are
            // various reasons that the creation attempt could fail. If it
            // fails, return null.
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(sound));
            return clip;
        }
        catch (LineUnavailableException e)
        {
            return null;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            return null;
        }
        catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void play (String sound)
    {
        Clip clip = createClip(sound);
        if (clip != null)
        {
            if (clip.isRunning())
            {
                clip.stop();
            }
            clip.setFramePosition(0);
            clip.start();
        }
    }

    public void startLoop (String sound)
    {
        Clip clip = createClip(sound);
        if (clip != null)
        {
            if (clip.isRunning())
            {
                clip.stop();
            }
                clip.setFramePosition(0);
                clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
                activeClip = clip;
        }
    }

    public void stopLoop ()
    {
        if (activeClip != null) {
          if (activeClip.isRunning()) {
            activeClip.stop();
          }
        }
    }

}
```

So my main problem is with the loops. When I have one object starting a loop with one audio file, it starts and stops fine, but when I have two objects simultaneous making a call to startLoop, only the most recent one will stop and the other one will keep going. I've thought about putting each clip with a name into a HashMap so I can distinguish each clip by name but constantly get a NullPointerException error not matter how I try to "put" it into a Map

Here's the version where I try to put it into a HashMap.
Essentially similar code, but each time a play or startloop is called, the string acts as the key and stores the clip so you can retrieve it later to stop the loop. But every time I do this I get NullPointerException at the lines were I try to put it into the Map:

```
    package sounds;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Playlist
{

    //private Clip activeClip;

    //Here
    private HashMap<String, Clip> list;

    /**
     * Creates an audio clip from a sound file.
     */
    public Clip createClip (String soundFile)
    {
        String fileName = "/sounds/" + soundFile + ".wav";
        // Opening the sound file this way will work no matter how the
        // project is exported. The only restriction is that the
        // sound files must be stored in a package.
        try (BufferedInputStream sound = new BufferedInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName)))
        {
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(sound));
            return clip;
        }
        catch (LineUnavailableException e)
        {
            return null;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            return null;
        }
        catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void play (String sound)
    {
        Clip clip = createClip(sound);
        //Here
        list.put(sound, clip);
        if (clip != null)
        {
            if (clip.isRunning())
            {
                clip.stop();
            }
            clip.setFramePosition(0);
            clip.start();
        }
    }

    public void startLoop (String sound)
    {
        Clip clip = createClip(sound);
        //Here
        list.put(soundFile, clip);
        if (clip != null)
        {
            if (clip.isRunning())
            {
                clip.stop();
            }
                clip.setFramePosition(0);
                clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
        }
    }

    public void stopLoop (String sound)
    {
        //Here
        Clip clip = (Clip) list.get(sound);
        if (clip != null) {
          if (clip.isRunning()) {
            clip.stop();
          }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please show us the `HashMap` version of your code?

Comment: I've updated the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't instantiate your HashMap named "list".

```
private HashMap<String, Clip> list = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: Yeah... such a silly mistake. Can't believe it took me this long to see it